# how to get login information from azure ad nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, passport.js, saml

I have azure ad working good with my nodejs web app for login. I am trying to receive the users login info from my backend, and then output that info on screen, however, I cannot seem to find the right way to do that, or a way to do that at all. I tried req.user, or req.session.user, but doesn't seem to work...

please let me know if anyone could help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the login information of a user from [Azure AD Audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs).

Programmatically you can use MS Graph to achieve this.please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

***Code sample,***

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

let res = await client.api('/auditLogs/directoryAudits')
    .get();
```

To implement your NodeJS code please go through step-by-step guide in [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node?tutorial-step=1).